# Transfer PrivateKey from KeyStore, use in OpenSSL with JNI

Tags: java, android, encryption, openssl

I have Android application which using WebRTC. All works perfect. But now, main problem, with encryption.

For making call and transfer data, WebRTC creates and uses a single `KeyPair` for every call. But I want to use custom `KeyPair` from `AndroidKeyStore`. For this problem I need to send own `KeyPair` to OpenSSL shared object to work.

The fix will be in NATIVE OpenSSL code, where WebRTC is getting OpenSSL context for encryption data using this function (`opensslidnetity.cc`):

```
bool OpenSSLIdentity::ConfigureIdentity
{
    ...
}
```

How transfer PK from AndroidKeyStore to WebRTC native code? **Another case, how set custom PK for WebRTC encryption work?**

---

**AndroidKeyStore**

In Java I can open the KeyStore (`AndroidKeyStore`) and get the public key - which ready to transfer (has bytes of key with method - `getEncoded()`). Also I can get private Key for encryption data, but I can't send this key in bytes, because `getEncoded()` return null. In this case, I thought, I can get `PublicKey` and `PrivateKey` and save them in bytes array. And after, call prepared methods in native code.

---

**UPDATE**: There is something similar located in google.source.chromium. Where they get key from Android KeyStore and creating OpenSSL context in native code. Native class for getting and using AndroidKeyStore for TLS - [Link 1](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/android/keystore.cc) and [Link 2](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/android/keystore_openssl.cc#).

Comment: I think Alex is right. However, there's a lot of interesting things you can do with Reflection.

Comment: I don't think so, because it's encrypt working, and java realization based on native... If with reflection it would be so easy, there was no protection..

Comment: Please ensure my edits to the title were correct. I though you were using Java and then calling into OpenSSL (or other shared object) via JNI. But it sounds like I was mistaken.

Comment: It's Ok, Thanks for useful edits..

Comment: @GensaGames, are you able to solve the issue? I am facing the same issue. How to send private key to native to create EVP_PKEY using OpenSSL-3.0.8

Comment: @Vamsi Actually at that time we dropped this implementation. You had to recompile native libraries with your customized changes. It was 7 years ago, so I believe there should be some workaround or support from WebRTC already.

Answer (score 2):

Android Keystore does not expose the key material of private or secret keys, by design (see https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html). You options are:

- Present Android Keystore PrivateKey + Signature or Cipher as OpenSSL EVP_PKEY.
- Don't use Android Keystore. Perhaps you don't need the additional protections it offered compared to storing private keys inside your process?

Comment: 2) Don't use Android Keystore - I need to AndroidKeyStore, but I know, this is not best solution.

Comment: 1) Present Android Keystore PrivateKey - Maybe this is option for me. But how do it? Problem That I have only Alias and KeyStore, not password or signature...

Comment: You can obtain a PrivateKey instance from Android Keystore using KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore"); ks.init(null); PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, null);

Comment: I now how get PrivateKey in Android. I mean, how now send this Key to native OpenSSL code!

Comment: For an approach, see how Android's default TLS stack (backed by BoringSSL) uses arbitrary PrivateKey instances. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/conscrypt/+/master/src/main/java/org/conscrypt/CryptoUpcalls.java used by https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/conscrypt/+/master/src/main/native/org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto.cpp  and