# Convert Android PrivateKey to OpenSSL EVP_PKEY in JNI

Tags: android, openssl, android-keystore

I am using OpenSSL 3 in my android application and I need to provide certificate and privatekey in the OpenSSL method.

My application uses the certificate in the ***KeyChain*** and based on the alias, I am able to retrieve the PrivateKey (KeyChain::getPrivateKey()) (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/PrivateKey) and Certificate Chain (KeyChain::getCertificateChain())

But OpenSSL requires in the format of EVP_PKEY can be constructed by method - d2i_AutoPrivateKey(https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/d2i_AutoPrivateKey.html)

[Private::getEncoded()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/Key#getEncoded()) returns null, as the keys are managed by Android Keystore.

EVP_PKEY *d2i_AutoPrivateKey(EVP_PKEY **a, const unsigned char **pp(/*Here we need to give the PrivateKey in char format*/), long length);

How can i use the Android's PrivateKey to convert to OpenSSL format?

I referred to the question - [Transfer PrivateKey from KeyStore, use in OpenSSL with JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521225/transfer-privatekey-from-keystore-use-in-openssl-with-jni) but I dont get any information from the same.

Comment: Android contains multiple Keystore implementations, which Keystore type is the keys saved in? Because there is e.g. `AndroidKeystore` which contains non-exportable private keys. You can only use them via Android/Java/Kotlin API but not extract the private key.

Comment: I am using KeyChain, the certificates can be installed via filesystem(cert installer) or through any managed device profile (MDM)

Comment: If access to the private key data is disallowed then you can not use OpenSSL. What you could do is change the crypto implementation to use Java through JNI: call from C/C++ code via JNI to Java/Kotlin code, perform the crypto operation (sign, en/decrypt?) in Java/Kotlin code and return the output back to C/C++.

Comment: But my operation is not related to encrypt and decrypt but to enable Post handshake auth using openssl